# White underscore, black screen when booting

Tags: boot

I encountered the following problem and I would like some help if possible.

Recently I had this issue with my pc where when I boot, I see only a white underscore (steady white underscore, not blinking) and after some moments it would go to the Aorus logo and not boot to windows.

To add to my confusion, I have a Zalman Z9 NEO case, I have 4 usb's on top. When I unplug when ever is plugged on the 3rd (didn't test the 4th, 1st and 2nd show to be fine) EVERYTHING goes back to normal and no more white underscores.

What could be the issue to this?

My specs for a little bit more help are:

Ryzen 3 1200, Aorus b450 PRO , Corsair Vengeance 8gb 3000mhz, EVGA GTX 960 2gb, Kingston a400 120GB, WD Caviar Blue 1tb, Zalman Z9 NEO, Stock cooler, cx750 psu, NZXT Sentry 3 fan controller.

Windows 10 64 bit PRO.

Comment: Probably Windows installed in Lehacy mode and a conflict when booting with one or more USB devices.

Comment: In addition, you could try to reset BIOS and update motherboard and USB driver to check. Always when we could not boot, the MBR file could be damaged.

Comment: It happened suddenly. Windows is not installed in legacy mode as far as I know. Im on the last bios (I upgraded from f4 recently).